# FullCalendar - trying to display logo image in header

Tags: javascript, calendar, fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar for a sporting event calendar. It works great, but I would like to display the team logo in the top left corner above the calendar. I'm not quite sure how to approach this. I want it on the monthly view and am trying to get something similar to the image below. Not sure if I can do it through the JSON, or if I would need to edit the source code.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way to do it is using CSS background images.

e.g. if you have a calendar with a header definition similar to the one in your picture:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: '',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'prev,next today'
    }
});
```

Then using CSS you can set a background image on the "fc-toolbar" class which is used to contain the header elements, something like this:

```
.fc-toolbar
{
  background: no-repeat url("https://fullcalendar.io/assets/images/logo.svg")
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/500/ for a working example.

Comment: Awesome! Works great as long as the image is fairly small. Thanks!